# I can't run the HelloWorld.xcworkspace file

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

This is the error log I get from Xcode. So far I've been using the xcworkspace but now since I've added pods to my project I can't do this anymore as far as I read :)

So the build succeeds but:
[image]

```
2019-08-16 18:41:29.967914+0300 HelloWorld[5103:5848737] 6.6.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2019-08-16 18:41:29.987801+0300 HelloWorld[5103:5848024] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107afc6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105b14ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107afc555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   HelloWorld                          0x0000000102f70f2a +[FIRApp configure] + 138
    4   HelloWorld                          0x0000000102f70510 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 96
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001124c5311 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 280
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001124c6cad -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3932
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001124cc0c6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1617
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d116d6 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 904
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d19fce +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d112ec -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
    11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d11c48 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1091
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d0ffba __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 782
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d0fc71 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d149b6 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 576
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d15610 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d1471d -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111d196d0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001124ca9a8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 514
    19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112081dfa -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110fd3125 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110fdced6 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 283
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110fdc700 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109f97db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109f9b2ba _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011100e146 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011100ddfe -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 451
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011100e393 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 42
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107a63be1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107a63463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107a5db1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107a5d302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d7362fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00000001124cdba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    34  HelloWorld                          0x0000000102f70a00 main + 112
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010715e541 start + 1
    36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Have you added `GoogleService-Info.plist` to the project from the configuration steps, seems that it cannot be found

Comment: OMG THANKS !!!! It did the magic :) I only added the GoogleService-Info.plist with drag and dorp and seems it wasn't enough

Comment: Added it as asnwer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `GoogleService-Info.plist` to the project file. Seems it cannot be found